# tsql breadcrumb query

Tags: sql, t-sql

[image]I have the following CTE Query

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS lvl, id, catName, parent,
        CAST(id AS VARCHAR(128)) AS Sort
    FROM CategoriesMap WHERE id =2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.lvl + 1, c.id, c.catName, c.parent,
        CAST(CAST(c.id AS VARCHAR) + '_' + p.Sort   AS VARCHAR(128))
    FROM CategoriesMap c
    INNER JOIN cte p ON p.parent = c.id
)
select * from cte
```

The Sort(Tree) Column has output like this (for two rows)...

```
2
1_2
```

Where, `2` is a Category TVs and `1_2` means this is tree map `(1: Internet Tv, 2 = Jadoo Tv)`

Now can I return the Category Name with the Category Code as well?

something like

```
2:Jadoo Tc

1_Internet Tv: 2_Jadoo Tv
```

Thanks

Comment: pls try to copy the output, because it is kind of unreadable but definietly not understandable whhat would you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS lvl, id, catName, parent,
        CAST(CAST(id AS VARCHAR(128)) + ':' + catName AS VARCHAR(128)) AS Sort
    FROM CategoriesMap WHERE id =2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.lvl + 1, c.id, c.catName, c.parent,
        CAST(CAST(c.id AS VARCHAR) + ':' + c.catName + '_' + p.Sort AS VARCHAR(128))
    FROM CategoriesMap c
    INNER JOIN cte p ON p.parent = c.id
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: And what if I want a separator between them. For example. 1:electronics^2:tvs

Comment: just replace the '_' with '^' on line 7

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS lvl, id, catName, parent,
        CAST(id AS VARCHAR(128)) AS Sort
    FROM CategoriesMap WHERE id =2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.lvl + 1, c.id, c.catName, c.parent,
        CAST(CAST(c.id AS VARCHAR) + '_'+c.catName+':' + p.Sort   AS VARCHAR(128))
    FROM CategoriesMap c
    INNER JOIN cte p ON p.parent = c.id
)
select * from cte
```